# Get average of time in SQL or SSRS

Tags: sql, oracle, reporting-services, oracle11g, ssrs-2012

I am making an attendance system.
Here in the code:

```
SELECT
c.gregorian_date,
c.WORKING_DAY,
c.notes,
a.am_empno AS emp_no,
t.emp_name,
a.Time_In,
a.Time_Out,
a.am_att_status,
t.team_name,
t.line_manager,
(SELECT COUNT(a2.Time_In)
 FROM pp_emp_att_mst_v a2
 WHERE a2.am_empno = a.am_empno
   AND a2.Time_In >= '09:15:00'
   AND a2.am_date BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'mm') AND TRUNC(SYSDATE)
) AS Time_In_MTD,

**-- Here I want AVG(a.Time_In)**

FROM
dim_calendar c
JOIN pp_emp_att_mst_v a ON c.gregorian_date = a.am_date AND a.am_date = TRUNC(SYSDATE)
JOIN team_names t ON a.am_empno = t.EMP_NO
WHERE
c.gregorian_date = TRUNC(SYSDATE)
AND a.Time_In >= '09:15:00'
AND c.gregorian_date BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'mm') AND TRUNC(SYSDATE)
```

I want to get average of time_in.

I am also using this query in SSRS report, so if there's a way to get average of time_in in SSRS report please share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert your time to a numeric value and then you can average it and convert it back to a time. Assuming that you want a similar average for each employee for the current month then you can use:

```sql
SELECT c.gregorian_date,
       a.am_empno AS emp_no,
       t.emp_name,
       a.Time_In,
       ( SELECT TO_CHAR(
                  TRUNC(SYSDATE)
                  + AVG(
                    TO_DATE(a2.Time_In, 'HH24:MI:SS')
                    - TO_DATE('00:00:00', 'HH24:MI:SS')
                  ),
                  'HH24:MI:SS'
                )
         FROM   pp_emp_att_mst_v a2
         WHERE  a2.am_empno = a.am_empno
         AND    a2.am_date BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'mm') AND TRUNC(SYSDATE)
       ) AS avg_time_in_for_current_month
FROM   dim_calendar c
       JOIN pp_emp_att_mst_v a
       ON c.gregorian_date = a.am_date AND a.am_date = TRUNC(SYSDATE)
       JOIN team_names t
       ON a.am_empno = t.EMP_NO
WHERE  c.gregorian_date = TRUNC(SYSDATE)
AND    a.Time_In >= '09:15:00'
AND    c.gregorian_date BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'mm') AND TRUNC(SYSDATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

What is `time_in` column's datataype? Based on what you posted, looks like a string:

> `AND a.Time_In >= '09:15:00'`

If that's really so, consider storing date (and time) values in `date` or `timestamp` datatype columns; if it is `varchar2`, you can have e.g. `45:82:92` stored in there, and that's not a valid time value. If it were e.g. `date` datatype, database wouldn't let you store such a garbage into the column.

---

Anyway: presuming this is really a string, then convert it to timestamp (so that extract function does its job), multiply hours by 60 (so that you'd get minutes) and add minutes themselves. Calculate average number of minutes and convert that number back to hours:minutes format.

Sample data:

```
SQL>  WITH
  2     test (id, time_in)
  3     AS
  4        (SELECT 1, '08:44' FROM DUAL
  5         UNION ALL
  6         SELECT 2, '08:28' FROM DUAL
  7         UNION ALL
  8         SELECT 3, '08:52' FROM DUAL
  9         UNION ALL
 10         SELECT 4, '08:59' FROM DUAL
 11         UNION ALL
 12         SELECT 5, '08:35' FROM DUAL),
```

Query:

```
 13     temp
 14     AS
 15        (SELECT AVG (
 16                     EXTRACT (HOUR FROM TO_TIMESTAMP (time_in, 'hh24:mi')) * 60
 17                   + EXTRACT (MINUTE FROM TO_TIMESTAMP (time_in, 'hh24:mi'))) AS avg_num
 18           FROM test)
 19  SELECT    LPAD (TRUNC (avg_num / 60), 2, '0')
 20         || ':'
 21         || ROUND ((avg_num / 60 - TRUNC (avg_num / 60)) * 60) avg_time_in
 22    FROM temp;

AVG_TIME_IN
-------------------------------------------
08:44
```

Is that correct?

```
SQL> select (44 + 28 + 52 + 59 + 35) / 5 as avg_minutes from dual;

AVG_MINUTES
-----------
       43,6     --> rounded, it makes 44 minutes
```

---

If `time_in` is stored into `date` datatype column, you'd do similarly: convert date to timestamp first, and the rest is as in above example.

Sample data:

```
SQL> WITH
  2     test (id, time_in)
  3     AS
  4        (SELECT 1, TO_DATE ('08.09.2023 08:44', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi') FROM DUAL
  5         UNION ALL
  6         SELECT 2, TO_DATE ('09.09.2023 08:28', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi') FROM DUAL
  7         UNION ALL
  8         SELECT 3, TO_DATE ('10.09.2023 08:52', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi') FROM DUAL
  9         UNION ALL
 10         SELECT 4, TO_DATE ('11.09.2023 08:59', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi') FROM DUAL
 11         UNION ALL
 12         SELECT 5, TO_DATE ('12.09.2023 08:35', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi') FROM DUAL),
```

Query:

```
 13     temp
 14     AS
 15        (SELECT AVG (
 16                     EXTRACT (HOUR FROM CAST (time_in AS TIMESTAMP)) * 60
 17                   + EXTRACT (MINUTE FROM CAST (time_in AS TIMESTAMP))) AS avg_num
 18           FROM test)
 19  SELECT    LPAD (TRUNC (avg_num / 60), 2, '0')
 20         || ':'
 21         || ROUND ((avg_num / 60 - TRUNC (avg_num / 60)) * 60) avg_time_in
 22    FROM temp;

AVG_TIME_IN
-------------------------------------------
08:44
```